# Is it possible to declare operator= private and have it synthesized by the compiler at the same time in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, operators

I am happy with the operator =, which is synthesized by the compiler automatically. But I want it to be private and do not want to bloat my code with page long definitions of the type

```
Foo& Foo::operator= (const Foo& foo)
{
    if (this == &foo)
        return *this;

    member1_    = foo.member1_;
    member2_    = foo.member2_;
    member3_    = foo.member2_;
    ...
    member1000_ = foo.member1000_;

    return *this;
}
```

Please, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Long answer: Yes. (see below) :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++11 it is:

```
class Foo
{
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& source) = default;
public:
    // ...
};
```

Unfortunately, most compilers haven't implemented this part of the new standard yet.

Comment: C++11 keeps on surprising me.

Comment: @user1097451: Let us know if it works in your compiler (and what compiler that is) :)

Comment: gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) and, no, It doesn't work, but I am happy to know that one day it will :)

Comment: After some investigation it is possible and it works! Also with my compiler. It just requires an additional command. Quoting [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/cxx0x_status.html) : "GCC provides experimental support for the 2011 ISO C++ standard. This support can be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options; the former disables GNU extensions."

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the Pimpl idiom.

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo() : pImpl(new FooImpl) {}
    // ... Foo's public interface, same as before
private:
    Foo& operator=(const Foo& source);  //- Foo's assignment operator is private

    struct FooImpl;
    boost::scoped_ptr<FooImpl>  pImpl;
};

struct FooImpl {
    // ... all the private data members that use to be in Foo
    // Note: using the compiler generated copy assignment operator
};
```

The copy assignment operator is private from the POV of Foo clients but you can still leverage the compiler generated copy assignment via FooImpl.  The tradeoff comes when implementing Foo's member functions as you now have to access the data through  the pImpl pointer.